# How do I display MathJax in chat?

Tags: support, faq, mathjax, chat

How do I display MathJax in chat?

What do I tell other users so they can display MathJax in chat?

Comment: Related: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/93/77)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3297/18398), we can use `start ChatJax`.  Just go to [https://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Erobjohn/math/mathjax.html) and follow the instructions.